# Ionic Appflow live update does not update

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-appflow

I am trying to use Ionic Appflow to do live update for my Angular-capacitor app. I have followed the documentation here: https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/quickstart/deploy.

I installed the Appflow SDK to my project with this command line:

```
ionic deploy add  
    --app-id="My_APP_ID" 
    --channel-name="Production" 
    --update-method="auto"
```

As the document says, it will listen to the "Production" Channel for changes and apply them to the app during the splash page.

Then in Ionic Hub (https://dashboard.ionicframework.com/) I deployed a newer version of my app with changes to the production channel.

This picture shows what I changed in the code, it was just changes of the theme Color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cThc0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV8l1.png)

After close and open my app in the emulator for serval times, no changes has been applied.

here is the list of packages versions

```
"@angular/animations": "~10.1.1",
"@angular/cdk": "~10.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "~10.1.1",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.0",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
"@capacitor/android": "^2.4.2",
"@capacitor/angular": "^1.0.3",
"@capacitor/core": "^2.4.2",
"@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.28.0",
"@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.28.0",
"@ionic-native/insomnia": "^5.28.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.3.5",
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.1",
"cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic": "5.4.7",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
"firebase": "^7.22.1",
"howler": "^2.1.2",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"stripe": "^8.15.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

Does anyone have any idea why the app is not updating? There should be no code required right? Just the correct setup.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what errors you are running into?

Comment: @Beefster Sorry for not provided enough detail about the question. I just edited it, please  check it out. Thank you.

Comment: As a helpful tip, make sure to prefix your links to images with `!`. Something strange might be going on with the image inserter because I saw quite a bit of this when running through the review queue. As for an actual answer, I'll leave that to an expert. I'm just trying to be helpful and welcoming. :)

Comment: Did you get to a solution? Is there any code required?

Comment: I made this today without writing code. Only the configuration as described under AppFlow, mainly adding `ionic deploy add --update-method=none --app-id="YOUR_APP_ID" --channel-name="YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME"`, building and publishing the app, and then just building a `web` build, and it will be published directly.